# How to execute OR, LIKE condition in WHERE clause in ZF2

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

I have query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `codedepartment` = <<VALUE>> OR `fullname` LIKE '%<<VALUE>>%'
```

and i code in model like this :

```
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$enim = $sql->select();
$enim->from('user');
$enim->where->equalTo('codedepartment',$jrs)->OR->like('fullname', '%'.$nm_pd.'%');
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($enim);
$result = $statement->execute();

return $result;
```

But that's not working. Can you help me ?

Comment: What is built sql query ( Try echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($enim) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to create a `where` condition with two clauses. It is not simple to figure out how to group your two where clauses. So, maybe you could make use of the [Predicates](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Db.Sql.Predicate.Predicate.html) API.

> The where method accepts several different datatypes one of which is a **PredicateSet**, containing, obviously, **Predicates**. This allows you to group your where clauses.
>
> [ZF2: Writing "advanced" MySQL where clauses MySQL](http://www.jaapsblog.nl/blog/view/29/zf2-writing-advanced-mysql-where-clauses.html)

In your case, you could try this code :

```
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$enim = $sql->select();
$enim->from('user');
// make changes here
$enim->where(array(
        new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet(
          array(
            new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator('codedepartment',
              \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator::OPERATOR_EQUAL_TO, $jrs),
            new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('fullname', '%'.$nm_pd.'%'),
          ),
        \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_OR
       )
));

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($enim);
$result = $statement->execute();

return $result;
```

You could also see the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#zend-db-sql-where-zend-db-sql-having) for more details.

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I got error in here 'Predicate\Operator::OPERATOR_EQUAL_TO, $jrs),' and the msg is not found. I also add 'use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql' . And i read that documentation

Comment: @FebryDamatrasetaFairuz Try to modify that line to : `\Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator::OPERATOR_EQUAL_TO`. If this doesn't work too, you could use directly the operator `=` instead of the constant `Predicate\Operator::OPERATOR_EQUAL_TO`. I've edited my answer, please see the edit.

Comment: it's working, but it's only working when i have a value for fullname. If i set a value for codedepartment it's not working (showing all record without condition) and if i set a value for fullname and codedepartment it's same. Not working. Why ? can you help me again ?

Comment: What do you mean by _set a value_, do you mean you give the other column _null_ ? If you want to use OR condition you should set a vlue for the two condition. If it shows all records you should look at your confition and try it with pure sql